# Network debugging port 25 timeout on dedicated server

Tags: networking

I have `hosta` and `hostb`, two dedicated server in the same area (same bay?).

Ping and communication towards these hosts are okay. But `hosta` seems to have all its outgoing communications on port 25 blocked somehow:

With `nc working-smtp 25` (and and port `80`) on both hosts. I figured that:

- `hosta` has all it's outgoing communication timeouted on port `25` only.
- `hostb` work fine.

Note that `working-smtp` is a working smtp server unrelated to both of them, practical to make test (and where I have put a `tcpdump` to double check connections.)

BTW, both hosts can ping `working-smtp`.

So I did a `traceroute -p 25 -T working-smtp`, and first two server in both traceroute are EXACTLY the same:

```
# traceroute -p 25 -T working-server
traceroute to working-server (xx.xx.xx.xx), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  A (xx.xx.xx.xx)  0.363 ms * *
 2  B (xx.xx.xx.xx)  0.819 ms  1.063 ms  1.166 ms
...
```

(A and B are network gateways out of my control from the dedicated bay.)

- On `hosta`, the next hops are `* * *` until it reaches max hop number.
- On `hostb`, the next hops are all valued and it reaches `working-server` in 6 hops.

If I do the same `traceroute` with port 80, both server reaches the target with the same track.

What conclusion could we draw ? Is there more test to do ? Should I contact my dedicated server provider ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to get from `hosta` to port 25 on a known working smtp server, and getting only as far as network gateway B.  Are you able to ping the smtp server from `hosta`?  It seems reasonable to me to contact the service provider.

Comment: @LarsRohrbach ``ping``, and ``traceroute`` on port ``80`` are all working like a charm. Some UDP packet reaches ``working-server`` if I do a ``traceroute -U`` (but its output strangely is similar to the one on failing TCP 25). So, this failure hits only outgoing TCP communication on port 25.

Comment: Check and make sure you don't have any outgoing firewall rules on ```hosta``` - it sounds like you might.

Comment: @PressingOnAlways wouldn't the traceroute be blocked before reaching A and B server ? Anyway on ``hosta``, I have checked shorewall, and I did a 'iptables | grep 25' (a bit rough, but since it didn't give anything...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I echo others' sentiments, that the hosting provider should be squarely in the line of enquiry (though as PressingOnAlways notes above, it'd also be worth confirming there are no outbound firewall rules in effect on `hosta`).  I think you've done an excellent investigation here (+1 from me!) and until the provider clarifies their position, there's not much more to say.

It would be fairly normal for hosting providers to block outbound connections to mail servers.  Some will want you to use their mail server as an intermediate hop, others will remove the block on a source-host-by-source-host basis on request (though they may ask you to explicitly accept an AUP first, to prevent their address space being used for hosting bulk senders).

I'm only posting this as an answer because your original question as written only admits of two answers - "*yes*" and "*no*" - and if it doesn't get an example of each, it'll stay unanswered, floating around like some kind of ghost ship, forever.

Comment: thanks for your insights. I have the clue: our provider does a SPAM check on what it sees going out on port 25. The provider does it's own SPAM checking on the fly and if this goes beyond a threshold, it'll block the offending dedicated server on all outgoing connection to port 25 until we clear out the issue.